# Mocking cross-fetch

Tags: reactjs, mocking, jestjs, next.js

I'm running tests via node with Jest, on a Next/React project.

I'm also using cross-fetch as well.

When I try to mock cross-fetch for my component

```
import crossFetch from 'cross-fetch'
jest.mock('cross-fetch')
```

```
        crossFetch.mockResolvedValue({
          status: 200,
          json: () => {{ 
            user : testUser 
          }},
        })
        render(<UserProfile />)
```

The API request in the getServerSideProps
always returns 500

```
export async function getServerSideProps({ query: { userId } }) {
  let user = null
  let code = 200
  try {
    let response = await fetch(`https://example.com/users/${userId}`, { method: 'GET' }) 
    let statusCode = response.status
    let data = await response.json()
    if (statusCode !== 200) {
      code = statusCode
    } else {
      user = data.user
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e.message)
  }
  return {
    props: {
      user,
      code,
    },
  }
}
```

I have a feel it has something to do with the tests being initiating from Node and testing-library library is simulating a browser, that the actual lib making the request is not being mocked for the correct execution environment (browser in my case).  But I'm not entirely sure.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not sure if this is the issue, but fetch expects absolute urls.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps it's not working because of the default export being a function. Try this:

```
//test.js
import crossFetch from 'cross-fetch';

jest.mock('cross-fetch', () => {
  //Mock the default export
  return {
    __esModule: true,
    default: jest.fn()
  };
});

test('should do a mock fetch', () => {
  crossFetch.mockResolvedValue({
    status: 200,
    json: () => {{ 
      user: testUser 
    }},
  });
  expect(crossFetch().status).toEqual(200);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I make use of `fetch-mock` (https://www.wheresrhys.co.uk/fetch-mock/) when testing `fetch` calls. You may need to provide a polyfill for `fetch` to be understood in the context of Jest tests, and this can be done with an `import "cross-fetch/polyfill";` in the file where `fetch` is being used.
Note that the Create React App generated environment handles the necessary polyfill imports, but I'm not sure if Next.js has something similar.